# If we have a company and we use proxy http ( not https ) , so are the security team can view the passwords of users clairely because of http?

Tags: http, proxy

If we have a company and we use proxy http ( not https ) , so are the security team can view the passwords of users clairely because of http ?

Comment: Even with an HTTPS proxy, the proxy owner might be able to read all of your password, proxies can play games with the certificates, especially when the company also controls the clients.

Comment: also if we connect to an external plateforme like gmail and not an internal plateforme ?

Comment: Yes. Before you trust the proxy, ask yourself if you trust your client. There are also reverse proxies which companies set (e.g. sites that use Cloudflare) and give their certificate's private key to the reverse proxy, so it can also see your passwords (there are auditors that certify that companies like Cloudflare don't abuse it, but there can still be leaks).

Comment: but, in general, if we use proxy http it is easier to view passwords ?

Comment: Yes, it's easier. But that's assuming that websites support it. For example, http://stackoverflow.com won't work, it would rather redirect you to https://stackoverflow.com/, so an http-only proxy will not be able to deal with it.